# How to solve syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')?

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /home2/twofouwa/public_html/wwwwwwwwww/wp-content/plugins/social-media-auto-publish/api/Facebook/autoload.php on line 45

Please how I can solve it?

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    // project-specific namespace prefix
    $prefix = 'Facebook\\';

    // For backwards compatibility
    $customBaseDir = '';
    // @todo v6: Remove support for 'FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR'
    if (defined('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR')) {
        $customBaseDir = FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR;
    } elseif (defined('FACEBOOK_SDK_SRC_DIR')) {
        $customBaseDir = FACEBOOK_SDK_SRC_DIR;
    }
    // base directory for the namespace prefix
    $baseDir = $customBaseDir ?: __DIR__ . '/';

    // does the class use the namespace prefix?
    $len = strlen($prefix);
    if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
        // no, move to the next registered autoloader
        return;
    }

    // get the relative class name
    $relativeClass = substr($class, $len);

    // replace the namespace prefix with the base directory, replace namespace
    // separators with directory separators in the relative class name, append
    // with .php
    $file = rtrim($baseDir, '/') . '/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $relativeClass) . '.php';

    // if the file exists, require it
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
    }
});
```

Comment: It tells you what is wrong. *"expecting ')' ... on line 45'"*

Comment: Provide your code.

Comment: Your code? Without this how we can correct the code

Comment: on line 45 - spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

Comment: please help me , i can't

Comment: Do you close the "}". And fuctio return?

Comment: There is no syntax error the in the code you've supplied.

Answer (score -1):

<sup>**Note:** OP has since modified their question.</sup>

Read the manual to autoload anonymous functions: http://www.php.net/spl_autoload_register

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong. You're missing the closing `)` when you end your autoload call. See below.

```
 spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

 }); //This part here
```

Comment: please check my post , and give me new full code . sorry